# EditText weird behaviour in ListView BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, baseadapter

I got a ListView, populated using `BaseAdapter`.
In the listview Item there's a numeric EditText:

```
...
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_quantita"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_quantita"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >

            </EditText>
...
```

When I tap on this EditText the numerical keyboard prompts for an instant, and then it's suddenly overlayed by a regular character keyboard. If I try to write something on this keyboard no text is shown anywhere.
Curiously, if I tap again on the Editext it behaves as it should, showing only the working numerical keyboard.

What can i do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation of `EditText` has many flaws when used in the `ListView`. Try to add this piece of code in your `onCreate()`:

```
int apiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (apiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
else
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

- Check if you have another EditText that might be overlapped with the numeric one.
- Create a new activity with only a numeric EditText and see if the same happens.
- Check the activity's code to see if something is being modified on run time. I don't think you could change the EditText type via code, but maybe something else is modifying it's behavior.

Hope it helps debug the problem.