# Add Item separately in ListView using Custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, spinner

I am facing issue related to add Particular one time in `ListView` without affecting other items. I also posted for that but no response.
**Source :** [Prevent ListView Item refresh when adding another Item dynamically using Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155365/prevent-listview-item-refresh-when-adding-another-item-dynamically-using-android)
My Custom `ListView` contains `TextView`, `Spinner` and `EditText` so I want to add items such a way that it does not affect already items and does not clear text if anything added by user and also does not changed `Spinner` index.
Please help me for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent ListView Item refresh when adding another Item dynamically using Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155365/prevent-listview-item-refresh-when-adding-another-item-dynamically-using-android)

Comment: `posted for that but no response.` ?? You had several responses. Please return to the old post. You have to answer there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store `EditText` and `Spinner` value with the position of `Listview` when `ListView` is reloads check for the stored data and assign that data to the position of `ListView`, assigning values should be done on `getView()` method. And you can use `SharedPreferences` to store the data. And for `EditText` use `TextWatcher`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like EditText might have some weird behaviour when used in ListView.
The answer of [Alessandro Roaro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2639515/alessandro-roaro) on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905567/edittext-weird-behaviour-in-listview-baseadapter) question helped me.